# How to insert data in ascending order into an array in vba excel?

Tags: excel, vba

In excel vba, I have a range of random numbers between 1 and 10 and they are not in order. What is the shortest way to insert these random number in an ascending order into an array? Also names in order from A to Z?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share any code you have.

Comment: Wouldn't simply using the "Sort & Filter" button in xcel do the trick. Seems vba is over-kill here..

Answer (score 1):

Sas, if it has to be done in VBA, this would do the trick (tested):

```
Sub Arrays()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim arr_MyArray() As Integer

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set MyRange = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A10"))
ReDim arr_MyArray(1 To MyRange.Cells.Count)

For x = 1 To UBound(arr_MyArray)
    arr_MyArray(x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Rank(x, MyRange, 1)
Next

End Sub
```

Come check out ExcelVBADude YouTube Channel!

Comment: That's a strange way to set a range. Why not `ws.Range("A1:A10")`

Comment: Sorry, used to setting non-contiguous ranges. And, you can't spell strange without range! hehe

Comment: 1 point for making me realize that `range("a1", "a10")` actually works and is equivalent to `range("a1:" & "a10")`, and that it is actually faster to provide 2 strings rather than concatenate them (tried in a 10000 loop)